# Omnet++ : random SendInterval sending out of range

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am having problem that the sendInterval I am setting is exceeding the limit I set for it.

Below I just added two lines that I am commenting

```
void EtherTrafGen::scheduleNextPacket(simtime_t previous)
{
    simtime_t next;
    if (previous == -1) {
        next = simTime() <= startTime ? startTime : simTime();
        timerMsg->setKind(START);
    }
    else {
        next = previous + sendInterval->doubleValue();
        EV << "THE PREVIOUS TIME IS " << previous << " THE SEND INTERVAL IS " << sendInterval->doubleValue() << endl; // Testing
        timerMsg->setKind(NEXT);
    }
    if (stopTime < SIMTIME_ZERO || next < stopTime)
    {
        scheduleAt(next, timerMsg);
        emit(sigSendInterval,sendInterval->doubleValue()); // Vector collect Send Interval Time
    }                     
}
```

I tested first with fixed sendInterval value

```
**.Host5.app.sendInterval = 1ms
```

> THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.001 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.001
>   THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.002 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.001
>   THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.003 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.001

From that I assumed **Previous Time 2 = Previous Time 1 + Send Interval**

Second **I assumed The interval time is the same as the one in table under Value** (The line shown in code)

[image]

Then with random sendInterval value

```
**.Host5.app.sendInterval = uniform(0.99ms,1.01ms)
```

> THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.001001856892 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.000998752
>   THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.001999544526 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.00100136
>   THE PREVIOUS TIME IS 0.002999144069 THE SEND INTERVAL IS 0.000997365

**Previous Time 2  not equal Previous Time 1 + Send Interval**

> 0.001001856892 + 0.000998752 = 0.002000608892
>    0.002000608892 -  0.001999544526  = 1.064366 usec

**The interval time is not the same as the one under Value as shown in the below table**

[image]

This is causing that the Host is sending out of the range 0.99ms,1.01ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `sendInterval` is declared in `EtherTrafGen.ned` as:

```
volatile double sendInterval @unit(s);
```

According to the [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:volatile-parameters):

> The volatile modifier indicates that a parameter is re-read every time
>   a value is needed during simulation.

The variable `sendInterval` is declared as a pointer to the object which has access to the `sendInterval` parameter. As a consequence, each time one reads the value of `sendInterval`, a new random value is returned.

In order to control the current value of `sendInterval` I suggest reading it only once and storing the result in temporary variable, for example:

```
void EtherTrafGen::scheduleNextPacket(simtime_t previous)
{
    simtime_t next;
    double sendIntervalTemp = sendInterval->doubleValue(); // one time read
    if (previous == -1) {
        next = simTime() <= startTime ? startTime : simTime();
        timerMsg->setKind(START);
    }
    else {
        next = previous + sendIntervalTemp ;
        EV << "THE PREVIOUS TIME IS " << previous << 
           " THE SEND INTERVAL IS " << sendIntervalTemp << endl; // Testing
        timerMsg->setKind(NEXT);
    }
    if (stopTime < SIMTIME_ZERO || next < stopTime)
    {
        scheduleAt(next, timerMsg);
        emit(sigSendInterval, sendIntervalTemp); // Vector collect Send Interval Time
    }                     
}
```